# c++ builder FloatToStr() bug

Tags: c++, c++builder

I use FloatToStr() but it have error !
I show you for my sourcode.

```
void __fastcall TForm1::FormCreate(TObject *Sender)
{ 
float i=3.14;
 Double j=3.14;
 Double k=0;
 Double m,n;

 Edit1->Text=FloatToStr(i);         //  It's show 3.14000010490417
 Edit2->Text=FloatToStr(j);         //  It's show 3.14

 Edit3->Text=FloatToStr(314/100);   // It's  show 3

 k=314/100;
 Edit4->Text=FloatToStr(k);         // It's show  3

 m=314;
 n=100;
 Edit5->Text=FloatToStr(m/n);       // It's  show 3.14

}
```

I ask ? Why ? All don't show 3.14 ???? !!! or It's bug in  FloatToStr() !!

1. Edit1->Text=FloatToStr(i);      //  It's show 3.14000010490417
2. Edit3->Text=FloatToStr(314/100);    // It's  show 3
3. Edit4->Text=FloatToStr(k);      // It's show 3

Thank for answer.

Comment: 1) a float can't represent 3.14 exactly, so you have error that shows when it gets promoted to double when passed to  `FloatToStr()`. 2 and 3) you're performing integer division (314/100) so the result is truncated.  Try (314.0/100) to use floating point division.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting different results because you're mixing integer division with floating point division in your code. *Integer division truncates everything after the decimal point*.

```
// This line is performing integer division
// and the final result is passed into FloatToStr.
// aka it's the same as calling FloatToStr(3).
Edit3->Text=FloatToStr(314/100);

// Again, the right-hand side is doing integer division
// and the result is implicitly casted to a double.
// aka it's the same as doing k = static_cast<double> (3);
k = 314/100;
Edit4->Text=FloatToStr(k);         // It's show  3

// These two lines implicitly casts int to a double
// when assigned in this manner.
m = 314;
n = 100;
// Now this is performing double division so you 
// get the expected result. It's the same as calling
// Edit5->Text=FloatToStr( 314.0/100.0 );
Edit5->Text=FloatToStr(m/n);       // It's  show 3.14
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem of why the float does not hold exactly 3.14 is the fact that all the numbers in the computer are stored in binary code, floating point numbers written in decimal code, can not exactly convert to binary code.

The number is written on a larger number of bits is a better approximation.

---

Look:

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Internal_Representation_Of_Numerical_Types

*long double (C++) = Extended (Delphi, Builder)*

```
number = <Significand> * 2^<Biased_exponent>
    // (there's also the sign bit, etc.)
```

**See that `<Biased_exponent>` is not a power of 10**, so it is difficult to obtain a good approximation.

---

Another help doc:

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Constants_And_Internal_Representation

---

Edit:

Of course problem is in division operation:

```
int / int = int        
double / int = double
```

Comment: Nope, it's integer division

Answer (score 0):

The expression 314/100 results an integer because you are dividing 2 integer values. If you want to divide using floating point operations you should use the expression 314.0 / 100.0

Using the decimal separator (.) in a static number in code makes the compiler using it as floating point value.